# Why do lightning data cables have chips?

Tags: cables, microchip, data

Is there a need for these chips?
[image]

Comment: please provide a part number of the chip and a link to the data sheet

Comment: `Is there a need for these chips?` Of course there's a need for that chip. Otherwise, it wouldn't be there :) What it does is hard to guess since there's no indication of what that chip could be. Apple is very secretive about their products so we may never know anything about how their products work exactly.

Comment: I was thinking if these could be 'malware' chips or there is an electrical need for data transfer or charging needs..

Comment: I think apple also tries to ID the cables to monopolize the sales of accessories (or license it).

Comment: To store the capability of the cable, e.g. how much current it can carry (the most important). Historically Apple envisioned lighting to be the cable for all (like USB type C today) so it's important not to use a thin cable on a high current device. But now it's less so because lighting is limited to small devices like iphone where standard cable is sufficient. However 5A USB type C cables also have ID chips.

Comment: @jsotola There is no available public all-inclusive datasheet for the lightning connector, because you have to be a certified MFI developer to see it.  AFAIK

Answer (score 10):

These chips are used as part of Apple's [MFI Certification](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) program. Basically, you have to be a certified developer to sell lightning cables.

If you buy a lightning cable from a reseller, you may receive a notification on your iPhone like `This accessory is not supported` every time you plug in the lightning cable. The pop-up is quite annoying. Your iPhone may then not charge, or charge very briefly, before mysteriously stopping to charge. It is not a hardware issue -- 5 Volts are still being passed through the cable -- it is Apple saying "you need a new cable!"

IMO, Apple also uses this as a kind of [planned obsolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence). It is my personal theory that the date of manufacture is also logged alongside the ID stored within the chip. This means that your phone's operating system knows how old the cable you're using to charge it is. So even if the cable is passing 5 volts to the phone, in theory, this would allow the Apple software to deny the voltage, preventing your phone from being charged. In theory, this would require you to spend more money to buy new cables.

Which, IMO, is the entire point of the MFI certification system - to make people overpay for "certified" cables, and choose when the cables break themselves so people have to buy new cables. Based on my experience, there is no hardware issue at play here, just a company using their monopoly to turn a profit.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong and I hate these monopolistic practices but there IS one non-evil reason for that certification lock: by preventing low quality manufacturers from producing cables, you prevent your users from having a low quality experience with your products. Have you ever tried charging your phone with a cheap 10 ft USB cable? Many people would swear "Man, I hate this phone and it's super slow charging".

Comment: "smart people know that a cable is a cable" how many smart people do you know? ;)

Comment: It's all fun and games until a cable breaks off in the port. Apple makes their Lightning cables out of proper materials, not sintered pot-metal that breaks off like plastic.  I call people like you "junkyard dogs" because you revel in trash-tier products, and you will not stop barking, ever, your populist but unfactual opinions. I can't believe you put an Apple/chip conspiracy theory in an *answer*.

Comment: I had one of these "slow charging" USB cables and cut it to investigate. The +5V and GND wires had about three tiny copper strands in them. Every cent counts!

Comment: That "this accessory is not supported" goes back to at least the iPhone 3 and the old 30-pin connectors, which did not have "security".  The phone is saying the wires in the cable are so thin that charging current is causing too much voltage drop to be able to charge. Of course I've heard E=IR is an Apple conspiracy...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, not sure what you mean by "security" regarding the old style 30pin cable. The cables themselves didn't have the authentication chip in them but the accessories surely did. Some features (like charging) would work without the MFI chip, while others (Nike+, digital audio, video output, etc.) required the chip. By signing up to be an MFI-certified OEM, part of the agreement was that you would only purchase the 30-pin connectors through "authorized channels".

Answer (score 1):

The hashed serial authentication Key is stored in the SOT.  [Here](https://youtu.be/kNe17lO5ewA) is a clone that does not work.